# FLASH : get inputtext value in AS2 SWF that running/load from AS3 swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

I made an e learning app in flash and I use AS3 in this elearning, in this app, I call / load a eksternal swf what I make with AS2.

in that external swf, I have an input text for user, and when submit button clicked, I get the value of the input text and parse it to a global variable and then show it to a certificate.

Its working if I run the as2 swf independently, but if I load that as2 swf from the as3 swf, I can't getting value from the inputtext. its say undefined variable.

can anyone help / explain about my problem ?

thanks befor, sorry for my grammr. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AVM1 and AVM2 are incompatible this way. Therefore if you need to communicate between both, you have to use LocalConnection. This is the only option to establish communication between ActionScript 2 and ActionScript 3 movies.

Comment: ty for your answer, can you explain about localConnection?

Comment: Here you can find an example in the asnwer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455649/communication-between-as2-and-as3

Basically you create LocalConnection instance in both AS3 and AS2 movies. One serves as a host and another as a client. Then you use send() method on client to invoke another method on LocalConnection declared in host.